# Deferred, rate limited Runnable execution

Tags: java, executorservice, runnable, rate-limiting

I'm writing an event handler that must trigger some downstream update process, which is currently done by dropping a `Runnable` instance into an `ExecutorService` (`execute`).

The challenge is: The event might occur one time in an hour (which is fine), but might also occur 100 times in a few seconds.

If an event occurs, the downstream process *must* be invoked *afterwards* to keep a data structure up-to-date. So it's not an option to say *"(now()-previousEventTime) < threshold ==> don't do it"*. Because the latest event might have changed *everything* although it was only 2 seconds later than the previous one.

But on the other hand, it was no big thing to defer the downstream process for a few seconds (e.g. 10-30 seconds), after an event has happened.

I'm thinking of something like this in pseudo-code:

```
private void onEvent() {
    if( isRunnableAlreadyPendingToBeExecuted() ) return;
    executeDeferred( updateProcessRunnable, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
}
```

See this example of a sequence of events:

- t+0sec: Event A -> Runnable queued to be run in 10 seconds.
- t+1sec: Event B -> nothing happens, as runnable already pending.
- t+8sec: Event C -> nothing happens, as runnable already pending.
- t+10sec: (deferred runnable is executed.)
- t+10.5sec: Event D -> Next runnable queued to be run in 10 seconds.

How could this be implemented in pure Java (up to 17), without third-party libraries?